# Weblogic redeploys performans with GC parameters in production

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection, weblogic, redeploy

When I use parameters about PermGen and GC in `startWebLogic.cmd(sh)`, after 3-5 redeploy without restarting, application responses more slowly in production. I could not apply the same problem in my local.

Parameters :

> -XX:-UseConcMarkSweepGC
>   -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
>   -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled

Specs:

> Java : java version "1.7.0_67"
>  Application Framework :Oracle ADF
>   12.1.2
>  WebLogic Server Version : 12.1.2.0.0

Comment: How are you redeploying? Are you stopping the old app, deleting it, and installing the new one? Or are you doing an "update"/hot deploy of the new app? Try one or the other and see if there is a difference http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24443/redeploy.htm

Comment: I update the ear. I don't delete old one. But If I don't use parameters, then no slow response.